# Is there a TypeScript library for speech recognition?

Tags: typescript

Is there a TypeScript library out there for speech recognition such as Chrome's implementation using webkitSpeechRecognition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much all .d.ts files are ending up on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped); I don't see one there.

Comment: Yeah. DefinitelyTyped was the first place I checked.
I'm not really expecting there to be one out there yet but had to ask.
I'll be looking around some more and if I don't find one I'll mark your answer as acceppted and create my own TS lib for it.
Thanks!

Comment: I am happy to report that a search for webkitSpeechRecognition in DefinitelyTyped now yields one result.